# Finding the closest number which is a power of 2 and smaller then the input

Tags: python, python-3.x

So far I have the code posted below. I am basically inputting any number into the function and I should be returned with the number closest to the input which is a power of two, and smaller than the input. Nothing is being printed or outputted.

```
def pow2(num):
    x=0
    expo = 2**x
    while num > 0:
        x+=1
        if expo >  num:
            print(expo)
            expo = 2 ** (x-1)
            return expo
pow2(55)
```

Comment: Your `while` loop is an endless one since `num` never changes. Also `==` means comparison, not assignment.

Comment: I edited the function, wouldn't the if statement break the entire while loop if I have return expo at the end? Even with this code nothing prints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop is an endless one since `num` never changes and you only recalculate `expo` if it is greater than `num`, which remains `False` if it was initially `False`.

A fixed implementation could be:

```
def pow2(num):
    x = 0
    while 2**(x+1) < num:
        x += 1
    return 2**x

print(pow2(55))
```

Note that the function only returns a value and does not print it. It is advisable for the functions to only return values and not have side effects such as printing.

Comment: @Kamal To be clear, is the expected output `32` or `64` if the input is `55`?

Comment: @Selcuk 32 was the expected output, I asked for the closest number which is a power of 2 which is also smaller, thank you for the help